# Right align icon in an ngFor <il> loop

Tags: html, css

Would create a list of items and align icon at the right.

```
<ul class=" list">
   <li *ngFor="let group of groupList">
      <div class="list-item"><span>{{ group.name }} (ID {{group.code}} ) </span></div>
      <div class="trash-icon">
          <img src="assets/img/icon_trash.png" height="20" width="20"/>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In CSS:

```
.list-item {
    width: 300px;
    display : inline-block;
}
.trash-icon {
    float: right;
} 
.trash-icon::after {
    clear: both;
}
```

The first line is aligned correctly, however, the following lines are indented.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

When I replace float by right align:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the flexbox display for that.

```
<ul class="list">
   <li *ngFor="let group of groupList">
      <div class="list-item"><span>{{ group.name }} (ID {{group.code}} ) </span></div>
      <div class="trash-icon"><img src="assets/img/icon_trash.png" height="20" width="20"/></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Your styles

```
ul.list li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.list li div.list-item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

ul.list li div.trash-icon {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The answer to the original question**

You don't really need `::after` pseudoclass when you want to clear floated items, you can just do the following:

```
.trash-icon {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

And here is the example:

```css
.list-item {
    width: 300px;
    display : inline-block;
}
.trash-icon {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="list-item">
    <span>SPAN 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="trash-icon">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/rss_circle_color-256.png" height="20" width="20"/>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="list-item">
    <span>SPAN 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="trash-icon">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/rss_circle_color-256.png" height="20" width="20"/>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="list-item">
    <span>SPAN 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="trash-icon">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/rss_circle_color-256.png" height="20" width="20"/>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: the problem is when the text exceed one line the dot is split to the second line

Comment: @infodev, It's because you set `width: 300px` to elements with `list-item` class, and on screen minimize there is no enough space to display it in one line. One of possible solutions is just remove `width: 300px` rule.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to replace .trash-icon float with text-align